# Android [Marker View not showing at Correct Positon After Clicking Onto LineGraph]

Tags: java, android, xml

I Have implemented line graph like this,

```
  <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_graph_container"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_138sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_day_percentage">

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                    android:id="@+id/chart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

But the marker view (as we are clicking on the line graph it is not coming over line graph ..marker view is not coming on touched position)

Like in the below image I have clicked at starting of the graph marker view is not at the correct position
[image]

Nd here I have clicked on end of the graph the marker view is not at the correct position
[image]

```
public class MfMarkerView extends MarkerView {

    private final TextView tvTitle;
    private final TextView tvSubTitle;
    private final ImageView ivMiddle;
    private final ImageView ivLeft;
    private final ImageView ivRight;
    private final List<NavHistory> navHistoryList;

    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    public MfMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource, List<NavHistory> navHistoryList) {
        super(context, layoutResource);

        tvTitle = findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvSubTitle = findViewById(R.id.tvSubTitle);
        ivMiddle = findViewById(R.id.iv_middle);
        ivLeft = findViewById(R.id.iv_left);
        ivRight = findViewById(R.id.iv_right);
        this.navHistoryList = navHistoryList;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
        try {
            String value;
            if (e instanceof CandleEntry) {
                CandleEntry ce = (CandleEntry) e;
                value = String.valueOf(ce.getHigh());
            } else {
                value = String.valueOf(e.getY());
            }

            if (e.getX() < 200) {
                ivLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ivMiddle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ivRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (e.getX() > 200 && e.getX() < 900) {
                ivLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ivMiddle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ivRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                ivLeft.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ivMiddle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ivRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            String navDate = getDateFromNav(value);
            if (!navDate.isEmpty()) {
                String formattedDate = DateTimeUtils.getFormattedDate(navDate);
                String displayText = Constants.RUPEES + " " + value;
                tvTitle.setText(displayText);
                tvSubTitle.setText("NAV as on " + formattedDate);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
    }

    @Override
    public MPPointF getOffset() {
        return new MPPointF(-(getWidth() / 2f), -getHeight());
    }

    private String getDateFromNav(String navRate) {
        String navDate = "";
        try {
            if (navHistoryList != null) {
                for (NavHistory navHistory : navHistoryList) {
                    if (decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(Objects.requireNonNull(navHistory.getNav()))).equals(navRate)) {
                        navDate = navHistory.getNavDate();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return navDate;
    }
```

And this is how i am using this marker view in my fragment

```
MfMarkerView mv = new MfMarkerView(requireActivity(), R.layout.mf_custom_markar, navHistory);

    // Set the marker to the chart
    mv.setChartView(binding.chart);
    binding.chart.setMarker(mv);

    // enable scaling and dragging
    binding.chart.setDragEnabled(true);
    binding.chart.setScaleEnabled(true);

    // force pinch zoom along both axis
    binding.chart.setPinchZoom(false);

    //Hide Background Grid
    binding.chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    binding.chart.setClickable(false);
    binding.chart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);

    binding.chart.setDrawBorders(false);
    binding.chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    binding.chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    binding.chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

    binding.chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    binding.chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    binding.chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
    binding.chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);

    binding.chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    binding.chart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);
    binding.chart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);

    binding.chart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
    binding.chart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
    binding.chart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);

}

binding.chart.setNoDataText(graphDetails);
```